# @Html.DropDownListFor returning null value despite ViewModel value used being populated

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, http-post, dbcontext, html.dropdownlistfor

I am using a ViewModel to pass details to a HTTPPost action and all fields are successfully saving to the database including the dropdown value but there is an error being thrown that the value cannot be null

My code for the dropdown list is as follows:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(c => c.Content.ContentTypeID, new SelectList(Model.ContentTypeList,
                 "ContentTypeID","ContentTypeString", Model.ContentTypeList.First().ContentTypeID))
```

Model.ContentTypeList returns a list of all content type found within the content type table, the table has 2 fields: ContentTypeID and ContentTypeString

I am trying to save the ContentTypeID to the table using the following code and while it is saving it is throwing me an error about null value, any ideas?

Comment: It should be interesting to see your Action's code.

Comment: your code in the controller

Comment: Particularly the method of the controller that receives the posted Form, the one decorated with `[HttpPost]`, including the received parameters and the code inside it. This way we can analyze what's going on with the binder.

Comment: All fields in the model are being set correctly and I have confirmed this in debug mode, the error is being fired on the dropdown and the message is "Value cannot be null. Parameter name items", not sure why the error is occurring when the value ID of the content type is being saved to the DB

Comment: I have been unable to work out why this is returning a null item for and so have changed this to just be a textbox for the meantime so that I can continue on. This is now posting successfully but when it returns to the same page I expected the fields to be blank but they are still populated with the previously saved data. I have added ModelState.Clear() before calling the view but this does not seem to have done the trick as others have mentioned